# Embedding a Traits UI gui of kind="subpanel" in another window

Tags: enthought, traitsui

In the traitsui documentation it states that

> Blockquote A panel is very similar to a window, except that it is embedded in a larger window, which need not be a Traits UI window.

Does anyone know how to make a larger window and populate it with the `edit_traits(kind='subpanel')` UI objects from a couple traited objects? I found an example of doing this in a wx window here http://gael-varoquaux.info/computers/traits_tutorial/slides_Traits_en.pdf on slide 23, is there a way to do this that does not tie me to wxPython?

An answer here will likely also answer a similar question ([TraitsUI, sharing an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143705/traitsui-sharing-an-object))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this always ties you to *a* GUI toolkit. That's the point: to embed the Traits UI panel into a larger, non-Traits GUI application that uses the desired GUI toolkit directly. The details outside of Traits are dependent on the GUI toolkit, naturally. If you aren't building a larger application that directly uses the GUI toolkit, you can ignore this functionality.

Are you instead asking how to build a Traits UI that happens to embed the full `traits_view` of another instance? In that case, you want to use a [`InstanceEditor`](http://docs.enthought.com/traitsui/traitsui_user_manual/factories_basic.html#instanceeditor) with `style="custom"`. [Here is the code from the example in the linked documentation.](https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/95e0bed62b83f311dba5c03c6b175ca96e4e70b4/examples/demo/Standard_Editors/InstanceEditor_demo.py)